# How can I change width of sprite Dynamically?

Tags: android, andengine

I want to change width of sprite dynamically but i can't perform it.!! Here i want to change only my white sprite i want to use these type of facility in my game in using AndEngine [I want to display life of player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra8vP.png)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I add my code its for temporary code you can change this code set your life of player

```
    life = 10;
    final Sprite whiteSprite= new Sprite(0, 0, testRegion);
    scene.attachChild(whiteSprite);
    width = whiteSprite.getWidth();
    scale = width/life;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            width-=scale;
            if (width > 0) {
                whiteSprite.setWidth(width);
            }
        }
    }, 5000, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how you can change width or height with modifiers of andengine.
Don't think you need it now. But it can be helpful for others.

```
entity.registerEntityModifier(new SingleValueSpanEntityModifier(duration, fromHeight, toHeight) {
        protected void onSetInitialValue(IEntity pItem, float pValue) {}
        @Override
        protected void onSetValue(IEntity pItem, float pPercentageDone, float pValue) {
            ((CLASS)pItem).setHeight(pValue);
            //where CLASS is the class of your item (Rectangle or Sprite...)
            //as Entity class hasn't width and hight params.
            // pValue is a variable from modifier. So, you write it like that.
        }
        public IEntityModifier deepCopy() throws DeepCopyNotSupportedException {return null;}
    });
```